# Flask route with directory path parameters

Tags: file, flask, directory, routes

I'm trying to implement a Flask view that renders a file from a directory `files` at the root. Ideally, the path would show up in the URL. However, `files` contains both files and directories. As different files are stored in different levels of the `files` hierarchy, I'm stuck.

Is there a way to implement a controller in Flask such that a PATH is accepted as an argument instead of explicit strings? I can sense this is probably impossible, but I'm not quite sure how else to proceed.

For example, I want something like

```
@app.route('/files/<filepath>')
def render_file(filepath):
    f = open('files/' + filepath, 'r')
    (...)
```

where `files` has some organization like this:

```
files
|________file1.txt
|________filedirL1
          |________filedirL2
                   |_________file32.txt
```

But the route would not only recognize top-level files with routes like `GET /files/file1.txt` but also something like `GET /files/filedirL1/filedirL2/file32.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Just found that you can use the path converter, which works fine:

```
@app.route('/files/<path:path>')
def render_file(path):
    (...)
```